# I am trying to filter a dataset and use k-means to make predictions but i'm coming up with this error?

Tags: python-3.x, k-means, assertion

```
 import pandas as pd
 from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, LabelEncoder
 from sklearn.cluster import KMeans


 # Read the excel file into a pandas dataframe
 file_path = r'\\uh01502854.bmwgroup.net\home$\Q554217\BSM.xlsx'

# Use pandas to read in the Excel file as a DataFrame
df = pd.read_excel(file_path)

# Filter the required columns
filtered_df = df[["Age at ablation", "Sex", "diabetes", "CVA/TIA", "MI", "CCF", "HTN", "anti 
arrhythmic", "rate control"]]

# Convert columns to numeric or string types
filtered_df["Age at ablation"] = pd.to_numeric(filtered_df["Age at ablation"], errors='coerce')
filtered_df["diabetes"] = pd.to_numeric(filtered_df["diabetes"], errors='coerce')
filtered_df["CVA/TIA"] = pd.to_numeric(filtered_df["CVA/TIA"], errors='coerce')
filtered_df["MI"] = pd.to_numeric(filtered_df["MI"], errors='coerce')
filtered_df["CCF"] = pd.to_numeric(filtered_df["CCF"], errors='coerce')
filtered_df["HTN"] = pd.to_numeric(filtered_df["HTN"], errors='coerce')
filtered_df["Sex"] = filtered_df["Sex"].astype(str)
filtered_df["anti arrhythmic"] = filtered_df["anti arrhythmic"].astype(str)
filtered_df["rate control"] = filtered_df["rate control"].astype(str)

# Encode categorical columns
encoder = LabelEncoder()
filtered_df["Sex"] = encoder.fit_transform(filtered_df["Sex"])
filtered_df["diabetes"] = encoder.fit_transform(filtered_df["diabetes"])
filtered_df["CVA/TIA"] = encoder.fit_transform(filtered_df["CVA/TIA"])
filtered_df["MI"] = encoder.fit_transform(filtered_df["MI"])
filtered_df["CCF"] = encoder.fit_transform(filtered_df["CCF"])
filtered_df["HTN"] = encoder.fit_transform(filtered_df["HTN"])
filtered_df["anti arrhythmic"] = encoder.fit_transform(filtered_df["anti arrhythmic"])

# Print the filtered and encoded dataframe
print(filtered_df)

scaler = StandardScaler()
numerical_columns = ["Age at ablation"]
filtered_df[numerical_columns] = scaler.fit_transform(filtered_df[numerical_columns])

# One-hot encode categorical columns
filtered_df = pd.get_dummies(filtered_df, columns=["Sex", "diabetes", "CVA/TIA", "MI", "CCF", 
"HTN", "anti arrhythmic", "rate control"])
# Scale the numerical data
numerical_columns = ["Age at ablation"]
scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(filtered_df[numerical_columns])

# Combine the scaled numerical data with the encoded categorical data
categorical_columns = [col for col in filtered_df.columns if col not in numerical_columns]
encoded_data = filtered_df[categorical_columns]
scaled_df = pd.DataFrame(scaled_data, columns=numerical_columns)
scaled_df = pd.concat([scaled_df, encoded_data], axis=1)

# Define the K-means model
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0)
kmeans.fit(filtered_df)

# Train the model
kmeans.fit(filtered_df)

# Predict the clusters for new data
new_data = pd.DataFrame([[70, 'Male', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes']], 
columns=filtered_df.columns)

# Convert categorical columns to numerical
new_data["Sex"] = encoder.transform(new_data["Sex"])
new_data["diabetes"] = encoder.transform(new_data["diabetes"])
new_data["CVA/TIA"] = encoder.transform(new_data["CVA/TIA"])
new_data["MI"] = encoder.transform(new_data["MI"])
new_data["CCF"] = encoder.transform(new_data["CCF"])
new_data["HTN"] = encoder.transform(new_data["HTN"])
new_data["anti arrhythmic"] = encoder.transform(new_data["anti arrhythmic"])

# One-hot encode categorical columns
new_data = pd.get_dummies(new_data, columns=["Sex", "diabetes", "CVA/TIA", "MI", "CCF", "HTN", 
"anti arrhythmic", "rate control"])

# Scale numerical data
numerical_columns = ["Age at ablation"]
new_data[numerical_columns] = scaler.transform(new_data[numerical_columns])

# Predict the cluster for new data
predictions = kmeans.predict(new_data)

print(predictions)
```

This is how my dataset looks
[image]

This is the error i get

---

AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py in _finalize_columns_and_data(content, columns, dtype)
981     try:
--> 982         columns = _validate_or_indexify_columns(contents, columns)
983     except AssertionError as err:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py in _validate_or_indexify_columns(content, columns)
1029             # caller's responsibility to check for this...
-> 1030             raise AssertionError(
1031                 f"{len(columns)} columns passed, passed data had "

AssertionError: 23 columns passed, passed data had 9 columns

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_2344\4014330585.py in 
1 # Predict the clusters for new data
----> 2 new_data = pd.DataFrame([[70, 'Male', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes']], columns=filtered_df.columns)
3
4 # Convert categorical columns to numerical
5 new_data["Sex"] = encoder.transform(new_data["Sex"])

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in **init**(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
719                         # ndarray], Index, Series], Sequence[Any]]"
720                         columns = ensure_index(columns)  # type: ignore[arg-type]
--> 721                     arrays, columns, index = nested_data_to_arrays(
722                         # error: Argument 3 to "nested_data_to_arrays" has incompatible
723                         # type "Optional[Collection[Any]]"; expected "Optional[Index]"

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py in nested_data_to_arrays(data, columns, index, dtype)
517         columns = ensure_index(data[0]._fields)
518
--> 519     arrays, columns = to_arrays(data, columns, dtype=dtype)
520     columns = ensure_index(columns)
521

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py in to_arrays(data, columns, dtype)
881         arr = _list_to_arrays(data)
882
--> 883     content, columns = _finalize_columns_and_data(arr, columns, dtype)
884     return content, columns
885

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py in *finalize_columns_and_data(content, columns, dtype)
983     except AssertionError as err:
984         # GH#26429 do not raise user-facing AssertionError
--> 985         raise ValueError(err) from err
986
987     if len(contents) and contents[0].dtype == np.object*:

ValueError: 23 columns passed, passed data had 9 columns

Answer (score 0):

seems like the data you're passing is 9 variables and columns you're passing are 23 and the problem is right here:

```
new_data = pd.DataFrame([[70, 'Male', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes']], columns=filtered_df.columns)
```

I'd either initiate an empty data frame and then add values to the desired columns:

```
new_data = pd.DataFrame()
new_data['column1'] = 70 # if 70 is the only value in the entire column
```

or I'd have:

```
len([70, 'Male', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes']) == len(filtered_df.columns)
```

meaning the number of values passed are equal to the number of columns.

Comment: Thank you, there is now am error showing in the next line that i cannot fix.                 
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_2344\1366763656.py in <module>
      1 # Convert categorical columns to numerical
----> 2 new_data["Sex"] = encoder.transform(new_data["Sex"])
      3 new_data["diabetes"] = encoder.transform(new_data["diabetes"])
      4 new_data["CVA/TIA"] = encoder.transform(new_data["CVA/TIA"])
      5 new_data["MI"] = encoder.transform(new_data["MI"])

TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Seems like you're assigning a new_data['col'] before initiating it. You can do something like: new_data = pd.DataFrame() 
new_data['col1'] = ''
Basically just initiating a value. There are simpler ways of doing that but laying it out step by step may help with pinpointing the error.